# DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT And Cannot Add Foreign Key Cons

Tags: php, foreign-keys, mysql

I was re-creating a table mytab with simple command `CREATE TABLE mytab(t INT PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR(100))` but it was giving me below error

> Error : Tablespace for table '`database`.`mytab`' exists. Please
>   DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

I search and found .ibd physical file on his data directory then I remove it manually and restart the service but now when I am re-executing the command its giving below error:

> Error Code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Error Code: 1215
Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

to fix error code:1215
first find out foreign key based tables and drop their constraints.

find FK constraints through

SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE table_schema='my_schema'

Drop the constraints and recreate the table and then recreate the required constraints.